# How to resolve this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Q: Exercise: 2 (qwrqwr: 2013-05-03)  For each month (with regards to year) present in the Battles table, find out the number of occurrences for each day of the week. Output: month (in "YYYY-MM" format), number of Mondays, Tuesdays, ...Sundays.

here is my code:

```
SELECT NAME, REPLACE(STR(YEAR(DATE),4), '', '0') + '-' + 
REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATE),2), '' , '0') + '-01',
REPLACE(STR(YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, -1, (DATEADD(MONTH, 1, 
REPLACE(STR(YEAR(DATE),4), '', '0') + '-' +
REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATE), 2), '', '0') + '-01')))), 4), '', '', '0')
+ '-' + REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -1, (DATEADD(MONTH, 1, 
REPLACE(STR(YEAR(DATE),4), '', '0') + '-' +
REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATE), 2), '', '0') + '-01')))), 2), '', '0') +
+ '-' + REPLACE(STR(DAY(DATEADD(DAY, -1, (DATEADD(MONTH, 1, 
REPLACE(STR(YEAR(DATE), 4), '', '0') + '-' +
REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATE), 2), '', '0') + '-01)))), 2), '', '0')
FROM BATTLES
```

=================
result : incorrect
Error.
The replace function requires 3 argument(s).

Comment: `REPLACE` can't take an empty string as the search parameter (the second parameter) like you do here, although that's not what it's complaining about.  One of your lines has an extra parameter.  Note that you appear to be doing things the hard way - I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, but there are far easier ways to accomplish whatever it is.  You might want to use a calendar table for your school exercise.  [There's also a `FORMAT` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

You have additional `parameter` on your 2nd `replace` function.

```
SELECT
       NAME
     , REPLACE(STR(YEAR(DATE),4), '', '0') + '-' + REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATE),2), '' , '0') + '-01'
     , REPLACE(STR(YEAR(DATEADD(DAY, -1, (DATEADD(MONTH, 1 , REPLACE(STR(YEAR(DATE),4), '', '0') + '-' + REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATE), 2), '', '0') + '-01')))), 4), '', '0') + '-' + REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATEADD(DAY, -1 , (DATEADD(MONTH, 1, REPLACE(STR(YEAR(DATE),4), '', '0') + '-' + REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATE), 2), '', '0') + '-01')))), 2), '', '0') + '-' + REPLACE(STR(DAY(DATEADD(DAY, -1, (DATEADD(MONTH, 1, REPLACE(STR(YEAR(DATE), 4), '', '0') + '-' + REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATE), 2), '', '0') + '-01')))), 2), '', '0')
```

**Here's the culprit.**

```
 REPLACE(STR(MONTH(DATE), 2), '', '0') + '-01')))), 4), '', '', '0')
```